# Crash upon returning to "The Underdark Exit"

Tags: technical-issues, baldurs-gate-2

[image]I have a big problem. I am playing BG2 ( GoG ). I have SoA + ToB. Until that moment i've had no crashes at all. When i defeated Bodhi in Ch. 6 and took the Rhynn Lanthorn to enter Suldanesselar. And BOOM when i try to return to Elhan in  The Underdark Exit i get a crash. And an error " BG2 stopped working "... I have had BG2fixpack and BG2tweaks instaled from theGibberlings site. Every other location works fine. I have re instaled the game multiple , with and without the fix/tweaks. I've sent the save to a frined and he also gets the same error.

Comment: Do you have a screen shot from the error?

Comment: Here You go. That's all i get. Stopped Working. And Not Responding.